# Will I be able to play as Psycho with a friends who does not have Psycho Pack?

Tags: borderlands-2

I am considering buying Psycho Pack and playing as Psycho with my brother. However, I need to know whether this is possible without him also buying this DLC.

So the situation: I have Psycho Pack DLC, other player does not, can I join their game with Krieg (psycho)?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will be able to play with your brother even though he does not have the Psycho Pack DLC.

The DLC only unlocks Psycho as a playable character, the files needed to have him in a multiplayer game are already in the game, regardless if the DLC is purchased or not.